# Char and graphical visibility

Tags: c#, char

running this code I see that not all values of char (from 0 to 65534) correspond to a symbol. It is rigth? Or I've to do something differernt to show  symbols different from a 'square'?

Thank you all!

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char x = Char.MinValue;

        do
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(x + " - " + (int)x);
            x++;

        } while ((int)x < (int)Char.MaxValue);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal. There are at least three possible explanations for a character being displayed as a square:

- Some characters may not be supported by the font the control uses.
- Not all Unicode codepoints are [assigned](http://unicode.org/glossary/#reserved_code_point).

> Reserved Code Point. Any code point of the Unicode Standard that is reserved for future assignment. Also known as an unassigned code point. (See definition D15 in Section 3.4, Characters and Encoding, and Section 2.4, Code Points and Characters.)

- One of the characters is actually supposed to be a [square](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm) (□) when displayed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth checking what fonts you have available to your application, and cross-referencing what you wan to be displayed (or expect) with the [Unicode code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/).